# Catching exit code after executing mysql query

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, batch-file, error-handling

I'm working on a bash script that will query mysql. I would like to add some error checking. Let say if the following query for some reason fails I want to catch the exit error and exit the script. For example this is part of my script.

```
QUERY="SELECT DISTINCT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE  table_schema NOT IN ( 'mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema' )"    

mysql -u user -pPASSWD --batch -N -e "$QUERY" | while read DATABASE TABLE;
do
  ...
  ...
  ...
done
```

How could i catch the exit code after the scripts run the "$QUERY". I was thinking something like this. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
mysql -u user -pPASSWD --batch -N -e "$QUERY" echo $? | while read DATABASE TABLE;
```

Any ideas

Comment: I think you mean to use single quotes, not backquotes, in `QUERY`.

Comment: @chepner, the backquotes must not be changed to single quotes, because those mean a completely different thing in SQL. But they must be either escaped from shell – or dropped, because they are actually superfluous – none of the backquoted items is a keyword.

Answer (score 6):

You are in the good way: `$?` is the flag to check:

```
$ mysql -h mydb <<< "SELECT * FROM MyDB.some_table_that_exists;"
$ echo $?
0

$ mysql -h mydb <<< "SELECT * FROM MyDB.asdfasdfasdf;"
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'MyDB.asdfasdfasdf;' doesn't exist
$ echo $?
1
```

So what you can do is to execute the query and then:

```
if [ $? ... ]; then ...
```