# Prevent empty files on error with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

Both dumping stdout and using the the `--result-file` option creates an empty file even when it's not able to connect.

Is there a better way to avoid these empty files on errors?  Other than deleting it after?  Or using a temp file, checking if it's not zero, and then replacing the old file?

Comment: @Drew, "connect", sorry.

Comment: how about a bash script or windows script to handle the return condition, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21025196/1816093 ... (the cleanup)

Comment: I'm looking for something before it starts writing the file

Comment: share your complete command what you are using.

Comment: What does the command matter? Basic mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout if there are spaces used in the coding as this might cause creation of empty files. Remove spaces between quotes as well as between letters and  '/'.

Comment: The command is fine, that's not the issue. I'm not asking what is causing the error, but how to prevent an empty file WHEN there's an error.